# Is it safe to change text datatype to nvarchar(max) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have an old SQL Server database that till uses the `text` datatype. I would like to change this to `nvarchar(max)` to allow for emojis and other modern stuff.

Is it safe to just change the database? Or is it safer to create a new `nvarchar(max)` column and update all rows to copy data from the old column to the new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the database using ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN

Just in case anyone mentions it, there were some old edge cases where data was lost or changed, but these have been patched ([MS KB 968914](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/968914/fix-when-you-convert-a-text-column-to-a-varchar-max-column--an-ntext-c) for example)